# string validation max 15000 characters not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate a textarea with max 15000 characters validation rule.

This is the rule I created:

```
array:1 [▼
    "text" => "required|string|max:15000"
]
```

Somewhere before I concat two inputs in this way:

```
$request->merge(['text' => $request->input('text') . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $request->input('sign']);
```

The code does not pass the validation even if the sum of text input and sign input is (according to [this website](https://charactercounttool.com/)) is 14988.
To calculate it, I just past the textarea value to the website and I checked the characters count.

**UPDATE**
If I log the length of `$request->text` input (even if the SAME string written in the log is 15000), I get these values:

```
strlen(trim($request->text)) => 15937
mb_strlen(trim($request->text)) => 15937
```

I guess its something with \r, \n or \r\n.

**SECOND UPDATE**
I created the string from random string websites, and I noticed the string is 937 lines, which is the exact number more than what the string should be.
It seems the PHP count every new line character twice.

Comment: Well if you see the effect only for a value that is so close to the one you actually specified, then we can probably assume that the validation in itself works as it should, but you are counting wrong ... or _different_ maybe, regarding stuff like line breaks coming as \r, \n or \r\n perhaps.

Comment: probably you right, but how can I check it? I am trying with logging the value of the request input

Comment: trim() it before doing the validation.

Comment: @nice_dev I tried, and if I copy the value from the log file to that web site, I get 15000 characters. It should pass the validation.

Comment: trim() is supposed to remove them by default https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: If value is 15937, how will it pass? Also, can you remove that merge thing and try as is.

Comment: @nice_dev I do not know why it is 15937. If I get the value in the log the string length is 15000.

Comment: _"It seems the PHP count every new line character twice."_ - a normal HTML form always sends line breaks as `\r\n`. PHP is just counting, what it got fed here. How are you reading the value from your log file to begin with? Are you transferring that to your local machine via FTP first? If so, what is the transfer mode set to ...?

Comment: @CBroe I am on my machine, I open the log file with pluma (debian editor).

Comment: Remove the new line characters then or increase the limit

Comment: @nice_dev yes, I did it. Thanks.

Comment: @GiacomoM  So, does it work?

Comment: @nice_dev yes. I changed the max value, based on the number of new line characters found in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you would rather do a string manipulation by your self before trying to validate, replace new line characters with `PHP_EOL` this is the built in PHP new line character to handle complexities that comes with dos and Linux new line characters.

when you copy paste from web most of the time `<br>` tag is converted to \r\n which is recognized as two characters. also most windows text editors outputs the same \r\n newline. that's why the double count.

You can use a regular expression or built in `str_replace("\r\n",PHP_EOL,$my_text)` to replace new line characters.

Either you can replace \r\n with just \n would work for your character counting purposes but will display new lines inaccurately depending on your application.